# I am trying to authenticate google sign in option but getting unresolved reference in .requestIdToken line

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I was trying to implement google-sign-in in my app, but it seems to not working.Showing error "Unresolved reference:googleSignInClient"

```
// Configure Google Sign In
    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build()
    googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
}

private fun signIn() {
    val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
}
```

A shortened version of app(module) level gradle file

```
dependencies {
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$rootProject.coroutines"
api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$rootProject.coroutines"

// UI
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.materialVersion"

/* coroutines support for firebase operations */
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.0'


// Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.0'



implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.0.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.0'

// Testing
testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.coreTestingVersion"
androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion", {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$rootProject.androidxJunitVersion"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
```

}

A shortened version of project level gradle file

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: If you understand Java Java, this article [How to create a clean Firebase authentication using MVVM?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will definitely help. If you want to learn how Jetpack Compose works, please check this article, [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8).

Comment: So the problem seems to be related to the `googleSignInClient` and not to the `requestIdToken`, right? How is `googleSignInClient` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this dependency, it will be solved.
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0'